# Mouse event tracking prohibition

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, jquery-events

I work with a site that can track mouse events, namely a click. Tracking takes place on clicks outside the browser limit.

Can I somehow deceive the site by prohibiting the sending of click events, but still be able to click on some part of the screen?

I tried to do this by prohibiting get requests, but failed. It seems I think in the wrong direction.
I would be grateful for any hint.

Comment: You can block all JavaScript, but some site are now working without him. https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000891.htm

Comment: There’s a site that tracks clicks that are not made within the browser window?! I really doubt that.

Comment: When a click occurs outside the browser, the window ceases to be active. This is tracked, not so put it, I apologize, but this should be avoided. @terrymorse

Comment: This site must have created listeners for events 'click' and 'blur'. Have you searched their JavaScript code for 'addEventListener'? Can you share the URL of this site?